# Datatype supported in Oracle but not in Excel VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I've written an excel vba which connects to Oracle and retrieves random 'n' records from a table. The query is working in Oracle but when i execute the vba, i get an error message "data type is not supported. Run time error -2147467259 (80004005)"

Then in my vba code, i removed the column which has data type = Timestamp. The vba works and retrieves the records.

I can use a conversion in my vba query but the table name is dynamic and number of columns differs from each table and hence i can only use "Select * from". Could you please help me on this.

Following is the query used. Does not works since the table has timestamp column

```
    sqlText = " SELECT * FROM " & tablename & " WHERE rownum < " & countx
```

The below query works since i'm querying a column name with data type character.

```
    sqlText = " SELECT name FROM employee " WHERE rownum < " & countx
```

I'm using ADO 2.8 and following is my connection string

```
conn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=" & Server & ";" & "USER ID=" & UID & ";PASSWORD=" & PWD
```

Thanks,
Dhanabalan

Comment: maybe you could add your query?

Comment: Have you checked if you have the Microsoft ActiveX library references enabled in VBA?  I am unsure which version of library is needed, but have seen those be issues for using Oracle/VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Following is the query used: 
        sqlText = " SELECT * FROM " & tablename & " WHERE rownum < " & countx . I'm using MS ActiveX 2.0 which is compatible i suppose. Since the query executes when i select a column with datatype character but throws error upon selecting a column with datatype timestamp.

Comment: You can add the query to the question itself by editing it. It would be helpful.

Comment: Try `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle` instead of `PROVIDER=MSDAORA`. The Microsoft provider has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for many years. You can download "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I do not have the privilege to install anything new. My office network does not allows that. My DBA suggested me to use Oracle ODBC connection string. I have Oracle 12c client (Oracle12FAT_0012.03) installed in my machine. Could you please let me know the connection string to be used.

Comment: Try anyway, perhaps OLEDB provider was included in your Oracle client installation

Comment: You can also have the Oracle SQL query cast the timestamp as a different data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for many years, it does not support Oracle data type `TIMESTAMP`. As far as I remember development stopped at Oracle 8i.

You have to use the Oracle Provider for OLE DB, in case it is not installed you can download it from here: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)

The connection string then has to be like this:

```
"PROVIDER=OraOLEDB.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=" & Server & ";" & "USER ID=" & UID & ";PASSWORD=" & PWD
```

You can also try ODBC driver. Situation is similar, the Mircosoft driver has been [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) long time ago and you must use the Oracle driver.

Connection string would be similar to this:

```
"Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Uid=" & UID & ";Pwd=" & PWD & ";DBQ=" & Server;
```